# Rounding two spaces after the decimal using multiple forms

Tags: javascript, php, html

I'm trying to get a answer that comes out like this in the text box "76.50" instead of "76.5" just FYI 'distanceTotal','rateTotal' and 'dimensionsTotal' each belong to different individual forms (three forms total) and have been converted to round off two spaces after the decimal successfully.

'hiddenTotal' and 'ultimateTotal' are cominig from the (fourth form) and have (not) been converted to round off two spaces after the decimal successfully and thats exactly what we need here.

```
function calculate() {
"use strict"; setValues();

var a = document.getElementById('distanceTotal').value;
var b = document.getElementById('rateTotal').value;
var result = document.getElementById('hiddenTotal');
var myResult = (a * 1.00 * b * 1.00);
result.value = myResult;


var d = document.getElementById('dimensionsTotal').value;
var e = document.getElementById('hiddenTotal').value;
var result2 = document.getElementById('ultimateTotal'); 
var myResult2 = (d * 1.00 + e * 1.00);
result2.value = myResult2;

}

<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('track_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('error_prepend_string', '<font color="black"><i>');
ini_set('error_append_string', "</i></font><br />\n");
date_default_timezone_set('America/Denver');

/** Rahdeeki Raheem Zumureae * Function Name: getDistance() **/

function getDistance($addressFrom, $addressTo, $unit){
//Change address format
$formattedAddrFrom = str_replace(' ','+',$addressFrom);
$formattedAddrTo = str_replace(' ','+',$addressTo);

//Send request and receive json data
$geocodeFrom = 
file_get_contents('http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?
address='.$formattedAddrFrom.'&sensor=false');
$outputFrom = json_decode($geocodeFrom);
$geocodeTo = 
file_get_contents('http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?
address='.$formattedAddrTo.
'&sensor=false');
$outputTo = json_decode($geocodeTo);

//Get latitude and longitude from geo data
$latitudeFrom = $outputFrom->results[0]->geometry->location->lat;
$longitudeFrom = $outputFrom->results[0]->geometry->location->lng;
$latitudeTo = $outputTo->results[0]->geometry->location->lat;
$longitudeTo = $outputTo->results[0]->geometry->location->lng;

//Calculate distance from latitude and longitude
$theta = $longitudeFrom - $longitudeTo;
$dist = sin(deg2rad($latitudeFrom)) * sin(deg2rad($latitudeTo)) +   
cos(deg2rad($latitudeFrom)) * cos(deg2rad($latitudeTo)) * 
cos(deg2rad($theta));
$dist = acos($dist);
$dist = rad2deg($dist);
$miles = $dist * 60 * 1.8515;
$unit = strtoupper($unit);
if ($unit == "K") {
    return round($miles * 1.609344, PHP_ROUND_HALF_UP).' km';
} else if ($unit == "N") {
    return round($miles * 0.8677, PHP_ROUND_HALF_UP).'';
} else {
    return $miles.'';
}
}

if (!empty($_GET['addrFrom']) && !empty($_GET['addrTo'])) { 
    $addressFrom = htmlspecialchars($_GET['addrFrom']);
    $addressTo = htmlspecialchars($_GET['addrTo']);
    $distanceTotal = getDistance($addressFrom, $addressTo, "N");
    $distanceTotal = sprintf('%0.2f',round($distanceTotal,2));
    $success = true; 
    } 

?>

<?php

$selected='';

function get_options($select)
{   

$rate=array('Economic Rate'=>3.00,'Standard Rate'=>4.00,'Express 
Rate'=>5.00,'Quantumtheory'=>6.00);
$option='3.00';




foreach ($rate as $key_rate => $value_rate)

{
if($select==$value_rate)
    {
         $option.='<option value="'.$value_rate.'" 
selected>'.$key_rate.'</option>';
    }
    else
    {       
         $option.='<option value="'.$value_rate.'">'.$key_rate.'</option>'; 
    }

}
return $option;
}

if(isset($_POST['rate']))

{

$selected=number_format((float)$_POST ['rate'], 2,'.','');



  //$selected= $_POST['rate'];
 //echo $selected;
}



?>

<?php

function getHiddenTotal($distanceTotal, $rateTotal){
//Change hiddenTotal format
$formatteddistanceTotal = str_replace(' ','+',$distanceTotal);
$formattedrateTotal = str_replace(' ','+',$rateTotal);
}

if (!empty($_POST['distanceTotal']) && !empty($_POST['rateTotal'])) { 
    $distanceTotal = htmlspecialchars($_POST['distanceTotal']);
    $rateTotal = htmlspecialchars($_POST['rateTotal']);
    $hiddenTotal = getHiddenTotal($distanceTotal, $rateTotal);
    $hiddenTotal = sprintf('%0.2f', round($hiddenTotal), 2);
    $success = true;
    } 



//$hiddenTotal ='';


?> 


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head></head>

<body>
<div align="center">


<form method="get" name"lion" id"blue" >  
<p class="distanceTotal">
<div id="d">

<p><b>Adress From<b>
<input type="text" name="addrFrom" 
value="<?php if(isset ($_GET['addrFrom'])){echo 
htmlentities($_GET['addrFrom']); } ?>" /></p>
<p><label>Adress To</label><b>
<input type="text" name="addrTo"
value="<?php if(isset ($_GET['addrTo'])){echo htmlentities($_GET['addrTo']); 
} ?>" /></p>
<p><input type="text" id="distanceTotal" name="distanceTotal" value="<?php 
if (!empty($distanceTotal)) { ?>
<?php if ($success = true) {  echo ''. $distanceTotal; } ?>
<?php } ?>" ><b><b>Total Miles<b><b></p>
<p><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Calculate Distance" />
</p>

</div>
</p>
</form>

<form method="post" name"tiger" id="black"  />
<p>
<div>

<select name="rate">
<option value="<?php echo get_options($selected);?>" /></option>
<input type='submit' id='submit_2' name="calc_2" value='Submit' />
<input type="text" id="rateTotal" name="rat" width="110px" value="<?php if 
(!empty($selected)) { ?><?php if ($success = true) {    echo '   '. 
$selected ; } ?><?php } ?>" /><b><b><label>Per Mile</label>

</div>  
</p>
</form>


<script type="text/javascript" src="js/precious_piece.js"></script>
<form method="POST"  name="ofrm" id="amount" class="cat_textbox" />
<p> Please provide us with the required information (<font 
color="#FF0000">Red</font> denotes required information):</p>
<p>What are the deminsions of the peices you would like us to deliver?</p>

<b>Total Wieght /Measurements</b><b><b><b>Lbs/ Inches</b><b><b><b>
<b>Totals</b><b><b><b><b><b>Price</b><b>
 <b><b><b><b><b><b><b><b><b><b><b><b><b><b><b>

 <p><b>Wieght</b><b><b>
<input type="text" name="qtyA" size="5" tabindex="5" oninput="calculate()" 
value="" onfocus="this.value='';" ><b>Lbs....<b><b>
<input type="text" name="totalA" size="12" tabindex="99" ><b><b>1.25<b><b>
</p>

 <p><b>Hieght</b><b><b>
<input type="text" name="qtyB" size="5" tabindex="5" 
onfocus="this.value='';" oninput="calculate()">
<b>Inches<b><b>
<input type="text" name="totalB" size="12" tabindex="99" ><b><b>2.35<b><b>
</p>

 <p><b>Widths</b><b><b> 
<input type="text" name="qtyC" size="5" tabindex="5"  value="" 
onfocus="this.value='';" oninput="calculate()">
<b>Inches<b><b>
<input type="text" name="totalC" size="12" tabindex="99" ><b><b>1.25<b><b>
</p>

<br><p><b>Total For Dimensions</b>
<b><b>
 <input type="text" id="dimensionsTotal" name="dim" size="50px" value="" 
onfocus="this.value='';" >
  <p>

</p>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/precious_piece.js"></script>
<form action="javascript:(calc())" method="post" name="panther" id="green" 
class="cat_textbox" /><br><br>

<input type="button" id="calculateButton" value="Calculate" 
onclick="javascript:multiply();" />

<input type="text" id="hiddenTotal" name="hiddenTotal"   />

  <p><b><b>UltimateTotal<b><b></p> 
    <input type="text" id='ultimateTotal' name="ultimateTotal"   />
  <br><br>
<input type="reset" value="Reset"><input type="submit" value="Submit" 
name="subButton" tabindex="50">
</form>


</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I need the inputs text boxes for 'hiddenTotal' and 'ultimateTotal' to read like "76.50" and "132.90".

instaed 
of "76.5" and "132.9".

Comment: Try `value.toFiexd(2)`.

Answer (score 0):

Take the `value` from the `input`, parse it as a `float`, and finally use `toFixed` to round and format the parsed value to two decimal places like so:

```html
<script>

function format() {
  let input = document.querySelector("input");
  input.value = parseFloat(input.value).toFixed(2); // set two decimal places
}

</script>

<input type="number">
<button onclick="format()">Format</button>
```

Comment: this doesn’t seem to work maybe I didn’t put it in the right place

Comment: The values that I’m using to get the answer have be converted to round two spaces after the decimal so maybe it’s because I’m trying to calculate values that are strings into another string?